# Nginx rewrite for URI querystring value

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I changed my website platform and i am now getting hits from google pointing to the old location of tag searches on my site. Basically i need to point:

```
http://www.website.com/articles/Subject%3Alist=Music-Oldies&review_state=published
```

to:

```
http://www.website.com/tags/Music-Oldies
```

..in my Nginx website file. Only the tag 'Music-oldies' needs to be extracted. 'Subject%3Alist' is actually 'subject:list'.

EDIT: '....articles/subject%3Alist...' should have been '....'articles?subject%3Alist....'

Comment: Why don't you just search the url for `list=Music-Oldies` (not necessarily using regex) and redirect it to the new url if a match is found? Is that string gonna occur at other parts of the url? or is there gonna be other urls with this string?

Comment: sorry, its not always going to be 'music-oldies' it can be anything. But the tag will always be a 'subject:list' variable. The former platform was plone, and for some reason it uses 'subject:list' for filtering dataset by keywords (tags)

Answer (score 1):

You need a rewrite directive like this:

```
rewrite Subject:list=([^&]+) /tags/$1 permanent;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working although i feel its close. I even tried:
rewrite [\?&]Subject:list=([^&]+) /tags/$1 permanent;

..to catch it on any part of the querystring but still no luck

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what's going on. Could it be the capitalisation of the word "Subject"? Maybe: rewrite [sS]ubject:list=([^&]+) /tags/$1 permanent; works for you?

Comment: after testing this exhaustively in a regex tool,it all works well with the actual ':' btw 'subject' and 'list'. The only conclusion i can make is that nginx is not decoding '%3A' back to ':' before testing